# Agda - Reverse-helper

Tags: reverse, agda, theorem

I'm trying to prove this lema

```
reverse-++ : ∀{ℓ}{A : Set ℓ}(l1 l2 :  A) → reverse (l1 ++ l2) ≡ (reverse l2) ++ (reverse l1)     
reverse-++ [] [] = refl
reverse-++ l1  [] rewrite ++[] l1 = refl
reverse-++ l1 (x :: xs) =  {!!}
```

But another function, reverse-helper keeps coming up into my goal and I have no idea how I get rid of it. Any guidance or suggestions?

Comment: We'll need to see the definition of `reverse`, since it seems you implemented it with helper function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that in the implementation of `reverse`, you call `reverse-helper`. In that case, you probably want to prove a lemma about `reverse-helper` that you can call in the lemma about `reverse`. This is a general thing: If you are proving something about a function with a helper function, you usually need a proof with a helper proof, because the induction structure of the proof usually matches the recursion structure of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with the different argument.

Since `++` is probably defined with `[] ++ a = a`, and `reverse (x :: xs) = (reverse xs) ++ (x :: nil)` it will be better to prove `reverse-++ (x :: xs) ys = cong (\xs -> xs ++ (x :: nil)) (reverse-++ xs ys)`

Comment: Well, it looks like it's the usual reverse with accumulator. You need far more involved proof for that, such as https://gist.github.com/vituscze/9116356

Comment: @Vitus It seemed to me that I proved something similar to reverse (xs++ys) = (reverse xs)++(reverse ys) in only a few lines. Maybe my memory fails me.

Comment: You might want something slightly more general like https://github.com/copumpkin/containers/blob/master/Semigroup.agda#L29.